# Separating Smarty If statement

Tags: php, smarty

I need a bit of help because I'm new to coding.

How can I separate this Smarty `If` statement:

```
{if $val.type=='PutLocker'}
<img src="/templates/svarog/images/stars.gif" title="Fast Streaming"> 
{/if}
```

I am specifically referring to this part:

```
{if $val.type=='PutLocker'}
```

I want to add another site name after PutLocker so it looks something like this:

```
{if $val.type=='PutLocker', 'SockShare'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{if $val.type == 'PutLocker' || $val.type == 'SockShare'}
<img src="/templates/svarog/images/stars.gif" title="Fast Streaming"> 
{/if}
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl).